# How to Receive WhatsApp Audios Messages Using Twilio for Dialogflow

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es

I am doing a chatbot with dialogflow-es and I connected it with twilio for whatsapp, but the problem now is that I want that dialogflow receive the audio´s user, but I don´t know how....

Comment: How have you connected Twilio to Dialogflow? What are you using to receive messages in Twilio and send them to Dlalogflow?

Comment: I followed this instructions to connected twilio to dialogflow[link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/tree/03676af04840c21c12e2590393d5542602591bee) _italic_

Answer (score 0):

In that example, there is a server that receives the incoming webhook request from Twilio. It looks like this:

```js
app.post('/', async function(req, res) {
  const body = req.body;
  const text = body.Body;
  const id = body.From;
  const dialogflowResponse = (await sessionClient.detectIntent(
      text, id, body)).fulfillmentText;
  const twiml = new  MessagingResponse();
  const message = twiml.message(dialogflowResponse);
  res.send(twiml.toString());
});
```

You can see that the application gets the text from the message from `req.body.Body` and the user's WhatsApp phone number from `req.body.From`. When Twilio sends webhooks to this endpoint for messages it sends all the information in the body of the request. You can see all [the parameters that Twilio will send in the documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request).

In this case you are looking for media that comes with the message, so you would first look for the `NumMedia` parameter. If it is greater than 0 then some media has been sent with the message.

Once you know how many media items have been sent you can then access them in parameters `MediaUrl{N}` where `N` is an integer. The media is delivered as a URL, so if you need to access the file you will need to download it.

So, you might deal with this like:

```js
app.post('/', async function(req, res) {
  const body = req.body;
  const text = body.Body;
  const id = body.From;

  const numMedia = parseInt(body.NumMedia, 10);
  if (numMedia > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numMedia; i++) {
      console.log(body[`MediaUrl${i}`]);
    }
  }  

  const dialogflowResponse = (await sessionClient.detectIntent(
      text, id, body)).fulfillmentText;
  const twiml = new  MessagingResponse();
  const message = twiml.message(dialogflowResponse);
  res.send(twiml.toString());
});
```

I'm not sure how you would deal with the audio with respect to Dialogflow, but that's how you access it.